# Unable to build Project after pod init in an old xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to init pod in an old code base. Whatever I do, I am not able to run my project after git init. There is always build error. I am getting following error,

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-F/Users/usr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-some_code/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit'
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-F/Users/usr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-some_code/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit'
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-F/Users/usr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-some_code/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacebookCore'
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-F/Users/usr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-some_code/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacebookShare'
> ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit

Even if my dependency pod file is empty then I get

> pods framework not found.

My Framework Search Paths is set to to $(inherited), which is build/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit.. I have also tried to set this path to pods folder under project. But nothings works. Even I have same issue with another project also.
Xcode version : 12.3
Code base is in Objective C.

Comment: Looks like the user changed? Does ```/User/usr``` still exist?

Comment: User name is fine, but ../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacebookShare part does not exist. Not sure why there is nothing.

Comment: I think the pod is supposed to provide that part. Did you do ```pod install``` ok.

Comment: Yes, I did 'pod install'. Tried to remove/add pod multiple time nothing worked so far.

Comment: Just a *wild* guess - for a pod project you open ```proj.xcworkspace``` and not ```proj.xcodeproj```. If you open the latter a lot of things will appear missing.

Comment: Nop. I am opening xcworkspace.

Comment: Have you tried `pod deintegate` and then `pod update` afterwards?

Comment: sure I did that couple of time also.

Comment: Old version of CocoaPods?

Comment: – Which cocoapods version are you using? – What happens after "deintegrate" – project is still opens well in xcode? I suspect, it migt be connected with arm x64 architecture, which is breaking build for simulators. Can you please provide more info on errors (more logs?)?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem before in the past, using *FacebookSDK* frameworks.

Of course, if you were using Swift, you could easily import it with **Swift Package Manager**.

Try to perform the following steps

### 1. Edit your podfile

Making explicit reference to the version and project name

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', ‘version’ :project_name => ‘myapp’
```

### 2. Delete build data

`MyApp-some_code` being the appropriate folder name for your app

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-some_code
```

### 3. Reinstall your pods

The command that you have probably tried a couple of times already

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

### 4. Manually add FBSDKCoreKit in Link Binary with Libraries

**Navigate** to Project->Targets->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries

From there click on the plus button and manually add the **FBSDKCoreKit** framework

### 5. Deselect copy items to destination's group folder

As per Facebook official documentation, available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit/ios).
Check out the point number 3, in particular.